# Raspberry Pi running python opencv on php

Tags: pi-3b+

I try to use the php running the python:

```
<?php 


$command=shell_exec('sudo python /var/www/html/FacialRecognition/simpleCamTest.py 2>&1');

echo $command;

?>
```

But the result show in chrome:

Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused (frame:2143): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I try any method to fix, but still not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the python script in a shell. The warning do you get there is mostly from a missing environment variable `DISPLAY=:0` by default. You should first try to run the python script from the commandline. Execute this command:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/FacialRecognition/simpleCamTest.py
```

Maybe you have to use another display number. If the script runs from the commandline you can look with `echo $DISPLAY` on the commandline what's the number of the display. Then you can try to execute the script from php with:

```
$command=shell_exec("/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash -c 'DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/FacialRecognition/simpleCamTest.py 2>&1'")
```

Comment: I tried and show other error: No protocol specified Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused (frame:6402): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have you checked if the script runs from the commandline?

Comment: No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(frame:6790): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
I try to command line to run still show the error

Comment: I saw other comment, because i installed xrdp for remote from my PC, the problem related to this?

Comment: I don't know anything about your python program. It seems it needs a graphical user interface. What operating system do you use? Is it *Raspbian Stretch Lite*? It is not a problem of php. You must get the script to run from the command line first. How do you start the script? Local with a connected monitor and keyboard, or within a window of a rdp/vnc remote desktop connection? Best for first testing is a local login.

Comment: Hi, i try to run the python script from the commandline. this is work

Comment: I used the Raspbian Stretch, and i use teamviewer to remote the raspberry

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any idea what you are trying. One time you say "*I try to command line to run still show the error*", now you wrote "* i try to run the python script from the commandline. this is work*". I don't know what the script is doing. Does it work silently or do any output? Then suddenly the *teamviewer* comes to play and I don't know where the script is running and so on ...

Comment: OK, sorry for my mistake, I re-install my Raspbian Stretch, opencv, php...before i use the xrdp to remote the raspberry. Now i change to Teamviewer to remote, and i try to use your method `rpi ~$ sudo /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/FacialRecognition/simpleCamTest.py` run on commandline, That is work. but I use `$command=shell_exec("/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash -c 'DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/FacialRecognition/simpleCamTest.py 2>&1'");` run on php. This is still show the error

Comment: the problem has been fixed. for my program problem. not is the OS problem.

Comment: @TonyLai You commented that you have fixed your problem. Please make a short answer about it and accept it after two days. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again since years.